# Windows Server proxy с подомена на порт

Tags: windows, windows-10, proxy, iis, windows-server-2016

Вопрос в том как поднять proxy с домена на порт:
Пример:

- `mydomen.ru` -> `127.0.0.1:80`
- `admin.mydomen.ru` -> `127.0.0.1:8081`
- `gitlab.mydomen.ru` -> `127.0.0.1:8082`

Comment: nginx нельзя установить?

Comment: хм.. а вообще, проще же должно быть?

Comment: @Qwertiy nginx нормально работает на win? Возможно я ошибаюсь, но разработчики nginx говорили что он не особо стабилен на win, да и не понятно что с производительностью (хотя это пока не критично)

Comment: @Qwertiy и разве iis не может работать как proxy? :/

Comment: Про IIS не знаю - можно сразу сайты с разными хостами разворачивать и не мудрить с прокси.

Comment: @Qwertiy задача на работе и нет возможности поднять несколько виртуалок под все сервисы

Comment: Каких ещё виртуалок? У IIS'а для сайта задаётся host.

Comment: @Qwertiy по поводу отдельный web сайтов проблема в том что допустим у Jenkins из коробке уже есть WebServer и не хочется особо хочется разбираться как заставить IIS запускать Java ради того что-бы перенести его с `mydomen.ru:8080` на `jenkins.mydomen.ru`

Comment: На порт никак. На своём компьютере можно прописать в `hosts` домены типа `mydomain.local 127.0.0.1`, `admin.mydomain.local 127.0.0.1`. В Apache можно завести несколько виртуальных хостов, в IIS можно указать домены в привязках (bindings) сайтов.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko нашел на просторах интернета статью: [medium.com](https://medium.com/@notCaseyWebb/deploying-jenkins-to-a-subdirectory-using-iis-on-windows-server-2016-6352589b7a6), где вроде речь идет о `proxy` c `mydomen.ru:80` на `127.0.0.1:8080` и обратно или я ошибаюсь? (но к сожалению не получилось повторить что описано в статье, сервер отдает 404)

Comment: @users Это возможно в случае установки так называемого реверс-прокси. Если вам нужно для локальной отладки сайтов, вполне можно обойтись hosts и виртуальными хостами.

Comment: @users Добрый день, случайно наткнулся на такое решение, может оно вам подойдет - cristianoliveira/ergo на гитхабе есть проект.